# Why can't change dns servers on Ubuntu 18.10;/etc/netplan is empty?

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

I have a server from zap hosting that comes with preinstalled 18.10 (fresh installation).
Now i tried to set the DNS Server (which is currently provided by the dhcp of zap hosting) to localhost, so I can setup a DNS server on the server itself in order to get postfix working.
The problem is, netplan is installed and the directory /etc/netplan exists, but it contains no configuration files.
Even when I add new config files myself, they seam to have no effect whatsover.
/etc/resolv.conf gets overwritten no matter what I do and /etc/network/interface contains a warning that I shouldn't use it and doesn't have an effect either.
So how do I set Ubuntu 18.10 to ignore the DHCP's DNS server and use itself as a nameserver?

Answer (score 1):

Zap Hosting put systems in place to prevent configuration of custom DNS servers so you can only buy them from their store. I would be a lot less angry about it if I didn't just spend an entire day figuring it out.